# Color legend with geom_text_repel and geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggrepel, geom-point

how can be colored the dots next to the legend labels? scale_color_manual or scale_fill_manual do not work. Also how can I change the dots in the legend to squares? Thanks

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
df <- data.frame(n=runif(8),y=1:8,l=letters[1:8],col=palette.colors(8))

p_vol <- ggplot(df, aes(n, y, label = l)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=l),color = df$col) +
  geom_text_repel(col=df$col)+theme_classic()
print(p_vol)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to include the color argument within the aesthetic call in `geom_point()`, setting `color = l`. Then you can use `scale_color_manual` to use the desired colors.

```
p_vol <- ggplot(df, aes(n, y, label = l)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=l, color = l)) +
  geom_text_repel(col=df$col) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = df$col)
```

Comment: It's not recommended to call columns with `df$` within `ggplot`. Would recommend renaming the `col` column to `colors` or some other non-argument.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try enabling `fill` from `aes()` using the colors you have in your dataframe. Here the code, I have used different colors because I do not have enough knowledge about the function `palette.colors` you used to have the colors. Also using `scale_fill_identity()` takes the colors directly from the variable in your data (Those defined in `fill`). Here the code:

```
set.seed(1)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(RColorBrewer)
df <- data.frame(n=runif(8),y=1:8,l=letters[1:8],col=rainbow(8))
#Plot
ggplot(df, aes(n, y, label = l,color=l,fill=col)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(show.legend = F)+theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_identity()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I found that fill is not necessary, in fact scale_fill_identity() even without fill use the standard ggplot colors, not the ones in the data frame